# How to cast a $2 \times 2$ problem in the standard quadratic programing form?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

Let $C$ a positive definite matrix, $\beta$ and $\epsilon$ constant parameters,  $\alpha$, $\eta$, decision variables.

$$J = \textrm{Tr}\left(\begin{bmatrix}\alpha & -2\beta\eta \\ \alpha & (1 - 2\beta \eta)\end{bmatrix}'C
\begin{bmatrix}\alpha & -2\beta\eta \\ \alpha & (1 - 2\beta \eta)\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}\eta \\ \eta\end{bmatrix}\epsilon^2\begin{bmatrix}\eta & \eta\end{bmatrix}
\right)
$$

I know $J\ge0$ because the trace of the sum of two quadratic forms, how to find the optimal solution?

I was expecting to be able to cast this problem to the standard form

$$\begin{bmatrix}\alpha \\ \eta \end{bmatrix}' A \begin{bmatrix}\alpha \\ \eta \end{bmatrix} + b \begin{bmatrix}\alpha \\ \eta \end{bmatrix} + c $$

### Edit:

I was asked in the comments for what I can get with a CAS. Evaluating $J$ then extracting the coefficients I can get a solution:

$$\displaystyle \left[\begin{matrix}\alpha\\\eta\end{matrix}\right]^{T} \left[\begin{matrix}2 {c}_{0,0} & - 4 \beta {c}_{0,1}\\- 4 \beta {c}_{0,1} & 2 \left(4 \beta^{2} {c}_{1,1} + \epsilon^{2}\right)\end{matrix}\right] \left[\begin{matrix}\alpha\\\eta\end{matrix}\right]
 + 
\left[\begin{matrix}2 {c}_{0,1} & - 4 \beta {c}_{1,1}\end{matrix}\right] \left[\begin{matrix}\alpha\\\eta\end{matrix}\right] 
+
\left[\begin{matrix}{c}_{1,1}\end{matrix}\right]$$

But I wanted to see if someone could point something less tedious

Comment: I tried sympy, what would you suggest?

Comment: I usually use SymPy.  You can append your SymPy code and show what SymPy did output.